# How to solve the requested resource that is not available for a servlet deployment?

Tags: eclipse, servlets

First of all, I have several servlet projects in the Eclipse IDE. 
Sometimes I face with the error called "HTTP Status 404 Servlet-The requested resource is not available". Then, I will try to clean the project and the server information. Sometimes, the error could be resolved but not always. I would like to know how to deal with this type of error.

Comment: Learn how to package and deploy your project correctly.  Eclipse is an IDE.  Packaging and deploying properly should not depend on your development tool.

Answer (score 0):

To make your resource available on your application server you have to:

1. Build your application (then the compiler generates the .class files)
2. Deploy your application on your application server. 
   To do it in Eclipse:

   - click on the "Server" view
   - right-click on your application server
   - choose "add and remove" and add your web application to the server.
3. Right-click on your web application and choose "Run on server"

If it doesn't work, maybe the servlet is not properly configured. 
Which application server are you using?
How are you making the configuration of your servlets? XML or annotations?